# How to restore original owner of a database on sql server?

Tags: database, authorization, owner

I am new on SQL Server.  I tried to see the Database Diagram and how it works.  I got an error since I am not the owner. I saw an article on how to change the ownership of the database and it works. After checking out the Database Diagram what it has to offer I regretted changing the ownership of AdventureWorks2012.  I found a better way to get the DB Diagram faster with a click of a button.  My problem is how do I put it(The Authorization)  back to its original condition/owner?  This is a learning experience for me. I need some help.  Thank you.